# Get Solaris/Linux package (from package repo) and put on server manually

Tags: package-management, solaris

First I'm not Solaris/Linux guy, pure Windows.

My problem:
I need to get ffmpeg executables on hosting Solaris servers. The first and obvious way it to take source code and compile it there. But there can be difficulties and I decided to defer this option. Option two: there are build packages for solaris 11 of ffmpeg (http://www.solarismultimedia.com/?q=node/53)

I don't have root permissions on hostring servers and can not perform any package operations. So I thought maybe it is possible to get package from the repo mentioned above and manually upload executables to server, and then do the stuff.

The problem is that I don't have any solaris machine to download the package. Actually only windows available.

What can be solution to the problem?

Comment: Have you _tried_ to compile ffmpeg? It may be not as horrible as you think -- at least some comments in ffmpeg's `configure` suggest that Solaris is handeled.

Comment: Not yet, I just never compiled anything in linux/solaris, and the first time I had to do it in uncontrolled environment. But it seems that I have no choice -)

Comment: Start with `./configure --prefix=$HOME/ffmpeg` (I prefer to test a program inside a separate directory before I let it mess up $HOME/bin ...) and if finished without error run `make && make install`. At least that's the normals procedure in Linux or Cygwin.

Comment: Ok, thanks, my hosting provider (actually nodejitsu) says that it is a bad pattern to compile very time I deploy the app. They say the will check the decision on not installing ffmpeg. Other wise maybe I will just setup in on VDS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to package and dependency management.

Unlike `rpm`, `deb` or other common linux packaging formats the Solaris system uses the `.p5i` format which does not contain all the installation files of the package itself. So the only other alternative is to mirror the whole repo on your server using the `pkgrepo create` and `pkgrecv`, set up an instance of `pkg.depotd` locally on your system and add that as a publisher.

But even if you do all that, you say that you do not have root privileges on the server and hence you would not be able to install anything using the the Solaris package manager `pkg` since it would try to install to locations such as `/usr/bin`, `/bin`, `/sbin`, `/etc`, `/lib`, `/usr/lib`.

The only other alternative is your option 1, of trying to compile packages from source.

I've done this a couple of years back on my department's CSE student login machine. It was also using solaris I believe but it doesn't matter. You need to compile the packages and its dependencies (which you cannot find already installed on the machine) from source and put them in directories like `$HOME/bin`, `$HOME/lib` and set up your .bashrc `$PATH` and `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` accordingly to pick up the correct binaries and libraries on startup.

Comment: While the `.p5i` files are just references to a remote repository, you can make `.p5p` files from Solaris 11 packages that contain the entire contents and install from them.   But again, without root access, that would just give you a bunch of files expecting to be installed in a directory you can't put them in.